# Optional(<OS_dispatch_data: data[0x7f97b145f2f0] = { leaf, size = 17290, buf = 0x11a63f000 }>)

Tags: json, swift, xcode

Trying to consume web service in iOS using JSON but end up with the above error in the last.. not sure why that's happening..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try correcting your do and catch..

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var lbl_studentID: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func btnfunc_getStudentID(sender: UIButton) {

        let data:String = "http://neo4j.nannasgroup.com/service.php"
        let url:NSURL = NSURL.init(string: data)!
        let req:NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest.init(URL: url)
        let res:AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSURLResponse?>=nil

        do {
            let dataVal = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(req, returningResponse: res)

            do {
                if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataVal, options: []) as? NSMutableArray {
                    lbl_studentID.text = "\(jsonResult)"
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("incatch" + error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }

    @IBAction func selectPicture(sender: UIButton) {

        let ImagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        ImagePicker.delegate = self
        ImagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary

        self.presentViewController(ImagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

        image.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
    @IBAction func upload_request(sender: UIButton) {
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

// Just Convert NSData to String

```
    NSString *String = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"responseObject:%@",String);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue **OS_dispatch_data** in *Objective C* when I tried to make a post request to the API and got some response. When I tried to print data that I received from API it printed **OS_dispatch_data: data[0x2813d9800] = { leaf, size = 442, buf = 0x103825200 }**.

**This was due to some error with the data from API side.**

**Explanation With Example:-**

I was working on **3DES** Encryption and Decryption when I encountered this issue. I was unable to use the data received from API for decryption which was encrypted at the server side.

**Decryption Code:**

```
-(NSString *)tripleDesDecryptData:(NSData *)input
                              key:(NSString *)key
                            error:(NSError **)error
{
    NSParameterAssert(input);
    NSParameterAssert(key);

    NSData *inputData = input;
    NSData *keyData = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    size_t outLength;
    NSAssert(keyData.length == kCCKeySize3DES, @"the keyData is an invalid size");
    NSMutableData *outputData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:(inputData.length  +  kCCBlockSize3DES)];

    CCCryptorStatus
    result = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, // operation
                     kCCAlgorithm3DES, // Algorithm
                     kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode, // options
                     keyData.bytes, // key
                     keyData.length, // keylength
                     nil,// iv
                     inputData.bytes, // dataIn
                     inputData.length, // dataInLength,
                     outputData.mutableBytes, // dataOut
                     outputData.length, // dataOutAvailable
                     &outLength); // dataOutMoved

    if (result != kCCSuccess) {
        if (error != NULL) {
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"com.your_domain.your_project_name.your_class_name."
                                         code:result
                                     userInfo:nil];
        }
        return nil;
    }
    [outputData setLength:outLength];
    NSString *tempString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:outputData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return tempString;
}
```

The data I received was encrypted JSON String. Since API returned base64 string, I could not use data directly for decryption in the above method (it failed).  I first converted the data to string using -

`NSString *jsonStringBase64 = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Then I reconverted back to data that could be used in the above method using -

`NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:jsonStringBase64 options:0];`

The decoded data was **null**. It was unable to convert back to data because the data was **inaccurate or corrupt**.

Then I changed options value from 0 to NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters in the above code -

`NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:plainText options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];`

Using *NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters* solved my problem as it ignored the Unknown Characters.

**From Apple:- Use the NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters option to modify the decoding algorithm so that it ignores unknown non-Base64 bytes, including line ending characters.**